# PHP Widget and do_shortcode

Tags: php, widgets, shortcode

I'm using PHP Widget which allows PHP code to execute from a widget. I tried using this code to execute do_shortcode but it's not rendering

```
<?php 
$lat = get_field('woo_maps_lat');
$long = get_field('woo_maps_long');
echo do_shortcode('[forecast location="' . $lat .','.$long. '" measurement=\'C\']');        
?>
```

If I echo a variable with simply `echo $lat;' it works. So the PHP Widget is working fine. The problem is echoing the shortcode in the widget. I can add shortcoded just fine to a widget but I need to be able to add the php variables where they are.

I tried adding `add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');` to my functions.php but it's still not rendering properly. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: why are you using single quotation marks for your measurement attribute?  Try dropping the escaping slashes and just using the double quotation marks.

Comment: That's what wunderground plugin uses in their example shortcode. Even if I remove that attribute it still doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried using the shortcode in your code with hardcoded values as a test?  Why not update your question with the code for the shortcode callback function so we know what is going on there.

Comment: Yes it works with hard coded values, it also works using do_shortcode placed into a template file.

Comment: [Is this the plugin you're using](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-php-widget/)? *(btw, your Question should contain this info)* . . . . . . . . . Also, `get_field` is a function from [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields) or is a function of yours?

Comment: Yes it's from ACF

Comment: What about the plugin?! . . . . Use @username, so the other party receives a notice of your reply.

Comment: @brasofilo the plugin code works fine in template files. The PHP widget works fine echoing the variables. For some reason do_shortcode isn't working right in the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the double quotes which are needed in normal shortcode usage in posts and pages for some reason when using do_shortcode the double quotes in the attributes where breaking the function. Working code below

```
<div>
<?php 
$lat = get_field('woo_maps_lat');
$long = get_field('woo_maps_long');
echo do_shortcode('[forecast location=' . $lat .','.$long. ']');        
?>
</div>
```